# How to load a div after the line break on click event?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery

I'm creating under Wordpress a single page portfolio. Each gallery thumbnail is a list item. 
When you click an item, it loads a sliding drawer (#DrawerContainer) pulling the content from the post with ajax.

I want this drawer to appear on the line after the clicked item.
Since it's a fluid layout, I don't know if the browser is displaying 1,2,3,4 or 5 items in a row.

I tried to append my drawer to every `<li>` but I'm afraid if I click a thumbnail,
the slider will open and make the other thumbnails jump to the next line.

So I thought the best way to prevent layout problems is to **call the drawer only after a line break**.

**How can I target the last li item in the row, and load a div after the line break of this row?**

If I'm not clear, here is the code I'd like to see rendered
**EDIT:** I just added the code to jsfiddle if you want to put your hands on it. http://jsfiddle.net/F6MvZ/10/

```
<ul id="portfolio-list">
    <li><a href="" class="ProjectWrap">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="ProjectWrap">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="ProjectWrap">item3</a></li> //end of first row (br/)

    <li><a href="" class="ProjectWrap">item4</a></li> //if I click this item
    <li><a href="" class="ProjectWrap">item5</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="ProjectWrap">item6</a></li> //end of second row (br/)

        <div id="DrawerContainer"></div> // the content of item4 appears here

    <li><a href="" class="ProjectWrap">item7</a></li> //end of third row
</ul>
```

and here is the code I'm struggling with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".ProjectWrap,.mosaic-overlay,.mosaic-backdrop").click(function(){
        var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
        //$('#DrawerContainer').slideToggle(500);
        $("#DrawerContainer").html("loading...");
        $("#DrawerContainer").load(post_link + " #container > * ");
    return false;
    });

        //Here is the part I'm stuck with now

    $(#portfolio-list).click(function(){
        $("<br/>").append('<section id="DrawerContainer"></section>');
    });

        //I assume the #DrawerContainer will generate a br/

});
```

Comment: Consider using `jsfiddle.com`, it will allow users easier to help you.

Comment: anyway `.append(...)` wont do it.. use `.after(...)` instead.

Comment: I think Ofir meant jsfiddle.net

Comment: Wow thx, I'm not alone anymore! :)

I managed to put everything together in jsfiddle but now I can't load the ajax to test it. I'm not familiar with jsfiddle maybe a <p> will be enough to test the Drawer.

Anyway here is the address: http://jsfiddle.net/F6MvZ/10/

Comment: Putting a DIV inside a UL isn't a good thing (i.e. valid) and might cause you issues. You could close the UL before the DIV and re-open another UL afterwards, or replace the UL/LI pairs with DIV/DIV and style as needed, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I just did a search and it looks OK validation-wise.
But I keep in mind the `</ul>...<ul>` around the div if a problem occurs. It should be easy if I'm able to target/detect the last `<li>` in a row and put my div after... Any idea? cc @OfirBaruch, @Gustonez, @superUntitled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/1/

Its an extension of what I originally wrote. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @techfoobar, 
It's very close to what I'm looking for. Actually while trying to adapt your code to my page, I noticed the first part wasn't necessary for the drawer to work. I also changed your classes into ids (I'm using classes to filter my portfolio items).

But now I'm having trouble merging your code with the one I used to load my ajax with...
And I also need open/close (slideToggle) the drawer with the "current" button.
Could you help me please if you have a little time? Here is the updated code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/9/)

Comment: Sure. I'll find some time in a few hours and work that out for you.

Comment: Your latest code seems to have some issues, the main one being that you are creating multiple elements with the same ID. Please note that IDs must be unique across the DOM. Otherwise calls depending on the ID will return only the first matching element. This is precisely the reason why we use classes to identify groups of elements and IDs to identify singular elements. See this for more info: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: You're right. Since you are deleting the previous element each time, you are nto creating duplicate IDs.

Comment: Ok thx, well I know the difference between ID and class but since I'm just learning jQuery syntaxe, I'm making a lot of mistakes. :)
I didn't noticed doubled IDs while inspecting the code. Are you talking about the "current" ID? Is the browser erasing the ID when I write `.removeAttr('id');` or is it just hidden (and kept somewhere)?

Comment: No, you were not actually creating elements with same IDs. That was my mistake when looking at it quickly. Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: Hi @techfoobar, I took some time to understand how you code work, I have a few questions. What does `.data('citem', this)` stands for? 

I added `var post_link = $(this).attr("href");` and `.load(post_link + " #container > * ")` when you create the drawer but I'm still unable to load my content... Could you just have a look at how I included it and tell me if the placement and my syntax is correct? Then I'll stop bothering you with it! Here is the fiddle [jsfiddle.net/RF6df/13/](http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/13/)